# failed to find target-26

Tags: java, android

i have a problem that i tried a lot of solutions but it didn't fixed even i tried solution in the forums in stackoverflow , the problem is i have android studio 1.1.0 that when i used it to make an application it shows me this : so is there any solution for this ? i don't have all platforms tool i have 21 and 23 only i tried to install 26 but i tell me there is wrong . thanks in advance  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hUqx.png)

Comment: You need to update your android studio

Comment: thank you for replying , and i will update android studio :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to anroid studio version 3.0+ to compile target 26 and above. Also upgrade your gradle version 3.0 and above.